# How to match a string of tuples in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have strings like `"(C,D) (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)"` and `"(C,D)     (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)"` or `"((C,D) (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)"`. How to return true if regex matches pattern like in first string (which is a one tuple or series of tuples seperated by one whitespace). I tried something like `"(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)[ |$])+?"`, but it does not capture the final pair of tuple. In case of 2nd and 3rd string it should return false.

Comment: Why do you use the lazy version of `+` instead of the eager one? If you write `+?` it will match only as much as it has to match to satisfy the expression instead of all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem of your regex:

```
(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)[ |$])+?
                ^^^^^
```

You thought that meant "space or end of string", didn't you? It actually means "space or `|` or dollar sign". A lot of special characters lose their special meaning when placed inside a character class.

You should replace it with `(?: |$)` instead. Also, the `+?` at the end should be a greedy `+`:

```
(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)(?: |$))+
```

Personally, I don't really like this "space or end of string" thing. I would prefer repeating the tuple pattern (especially when the repeated pattern is not long):

```
(?:\([A-Z],[A-Z]\) )*(?:\([A-Z],[A-Z]\))
```

Needless to say, you should match with `matches`, not `find`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a string of parenthesised pairs of comma-separated capital letters, with a single space between each pair, you could use a pattern like this:

```
^\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\)( \\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\))*$
```

That is: letter,comma,letter all in parentheses, following by zero or more occurrences of the similar parenthetic expressions, each preceded by a space.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you might be able to do that with:

```
\s*|\(([^()\r\n]+)\)
```

If the pattern would not return an empty string, would be `false`.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lm5BJb/1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\([^()\\r\\n]+\\)|\\s*";
        final String string = "(C,D) (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)\n"
             + "(C,D)     (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)\n"
             + "((C,D) (E,F) (G,H) (J,K)";
        final String subst = "";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
(
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lsckK2/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lsckK2/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

### Source

[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)